# How do i get the correct values from the com port

Tags: c++, serial-port

I'm trying to read a string from some hardware. and get the digits into int. so that it may be used. the string that is currently coming in is "a01y2345z". the first to digits are the channel and the last four is the value.

```
stringstream Channel_ss;
stringstream Data_ss;

SetCommMask(handle, EV_RXCHAR);

DWORD dwEventMask;
WaitCommEvent(handle, &dwEventMask, NULL);

char TempChar;
char SerialBuffer[512];
DWORD NoBytesRead;

for (int i = 0; i < 13; i++) {
    ReadFile(handle, &TempChar, sizeof(TempChar), &NoBytesRead, NULL);
    SerialBuffer[i] = TempChar;
    if (SerialBuffer[0] == 'a') {
        for (int j = 0; j < 13; j++) {
            if (isdigit(SerialBuffer[j])) {
                Channel_ss.put(SerialBuffer[j]);
                if (j == 2) {
                    Chan = stoi(Channel_ss.str());
                    Channel_ss.str(string());
                }
            }
        }
        if (SerialBuffer[3] == Secondc) {
            for (int k = 0; k < 4; k++) {
                if (isdigit(SerialBuffer[k])) {
                    Data_ss.put(SerialBuffer[k]);
                    if (k == 4) {
                        Val[&Chan] = stoi(Data_ss.str());
                        Data_ss.str(string());
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    string PrintChan = to_string(Chan);
    string PrintVal = to_string(Val[&Chan]);
    cout << "Channel : " << PrintChan << " Value : " << PrintVal << endl;
}
```

I'm trying to get it to print to screen 
Channel : 01 Value : 2345 
and the current result is :

> CreateFileA -> Successfully executed GetCommState -> Successfully
>   executed SetCommState -> Successfully executed SetCommTimeouts ->
>   Successfully executed Channel : 0 Value : 0 Channel : 0 Value : 0
>   Channel : 4 Value : 4 Channel : 4 Value : 4 Channel : 4 Value : 4
>   Channel : 4 Value : 4 Channel : 204 Value : 204 Channel : 2604 Value :
>   2604 Channel : 26704 Value : 26704 Channel : 26704 Value : 26704
>   Channel : 26704 Value : 26704 Channel : 267004 Value : 267004 Channel
>   : 2670704 Value : 2670704

Comment: Following [these guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) would make it easier for other people to help you. However, I understand that it may be hard to produce a simpler example of the problem if you have no idea what is wrong.

Comment: The following variables are undeclared: `Second`c, `Val`, `Chan`. I guess `Chan` is an `int` and `Val` is an array of `int`. But what is Secondc? Is that the character constant 'y' in your example? Also, if the first character read with `ReadFile` is 'a', you read the elements 0 to 12 of `SerialBuffer` even in the first iteration of the outer loop, which only initializes element 0 of `SerialBuffer`. In other words, most of the data you are reading is uninitialized. Is this intended? Shouldn't you first read all chars and then parse them afterwards?

Comment: If I understand correctly, the problem is either that the data you are reading from `ReadFile` is not what you expect or that there is something wrong with the parsing of the string and outputting of the individual elements. Therefore, I would recommend that, for debugging purposes, you first print out every single character read by `ReadFile` (either as text or as hexadecimal binary values) to determine if the data read by `ReadFile` is what you expect. If it is, then something must be wrong with the parsing of the string, and you can limit your example to that part of your program.

Comment: the data coming in is correct, has been tested, the code section is a function, the secondc and firstc are added externally which are the 'a' and 'y'. when writting the serialbuffer to the console the data is correct. j < 13 was a test i did to see if i could just get the channels correctly. it is supposed to be j < 3.

Comment: If you are sure that the data you get from `ReadFile` is not the problem, then, if my understanding is correct, the problem must be in the way you are parsing the string. Therefore, it should be possible for you to produce a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) without using the Serial I/O functions or the `ReadFile` function. It should be possible for you to only use the constant string "a01y2345z" in your program to demonstrate the problem, or several similar constants if necessary. That way, people will be able to help you more easily.

Comment: Without a compilable program which demonstrates the problem, it is not easy for people to help you.